# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Management

Tags: java, maven, github, wso2, mdm

I am new to Wso2-EMM i have imported project for GitHub integrated maven to eclipse can somebody guide me regarding where to download dependencies so as to debug the project.

Thanks Tanmay